# Salt ochestrator delay

Tags: salt-stack

I'm running a state file and an orchestrator inside a reactor, I'd like to know if it's possible to delay the orchestrator to make sure it runs after the first state file has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your reactor so it isn't calling both. instead have it call a different orchestration. that first calls the state then calls the fist orchestration that will use require on the first state.

as for the question, no reactor will just fire off everything all at once. it is best to do fine grain control over actions in an orchestration.